# Getting the text of the current slide in FlexSlider

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I am using FlexSlider on my website. I want to get the text of the current slide. I try to do it in the `after` function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        startAt: 1,
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: true,
        after: function(){
            var curSlide = $('#slider').data('flexslider').currentSlide;
            alert("current slide="+curSlide.text());
        }   
    });
});
```

I tried using the `text()` function but it's not working. How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried .val()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentSlide` returns the number of the current slide, not the element. You can use `nth-of-type` to find the element.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        startAt: 1,
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: true,
        after: function(slider){
            var curSlide = slider.find("li:nth-of-type("+(slider.currentSlide+1)+")")[0];
            var text = $(curSlide).text().trim();
            alert(text);
        }   
    });
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPpBD/238/)

**Explanation:**

1. According to the flexslider [documentation](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/flexslider#field_methods), each method has a reference to the slider object.
2. Testing around I realized that `slider.currentSlide` returns the number of the current slide, starting from 0.
3. We use the slider object and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the current slide element. We need to add 1 to `slider.currentSlide` because it starts from 0, and the `nth-of-type` selector starts with one.
4. I realized that the `find` method returned 3 `li` elements but only the first one was the one needed, that was why I selected the `[0]` element.
5. Finally I use `trim()` to remove the extra white spaces.

**UPDATE**

I realized that there was a better way to do it. FlexSlider assigns the class `flex-active-slide` to the active slide, so it is easier to get the slide element.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        startAt: 1,
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: true,
        after: function(slider){
            var curSlide = slider.find("li.flex-active-slide");
            var text = $(curSlide).text().trim();
            alert(text);
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: thankyou.It is working.But I need to understand it. I know meaning of nth-of-type,But what is find method do in flexslider and why you have added 1 to slider.currentslider and what about index [0]

Comment: I added an explanation and a better way to resolve the problem

Comment: I want to ask only one question why find methods returns 3 li elements as there is only one current slide

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I think that it is beacuse the `slider` element has other `li` elements inside (in addition to the slides), and all of them match the `nth-of-type` selector. Probably it won't happen if you use `$('#slider')` or something like that instead of the `slider` element. Hope that I managed to explain myself ;)